# Mailman: If a non-list member sends a mail, how to add his address as Cc?

Tags: mailman

I have a simple mailman setup which is configured to replace the Reply-To field with the mailing list address.

This is to allow a simple 'Reply' to go to the list, as this is the main use case.

Now in addition I want to allow non-list members to post messages. But in the current set up the sender will be in the From, and the list is in the 'Reply-To' - so even when list members click on "Reply to all" in their email client, it will only include the 'Reply-to' field, not the From (the original sender).

So is it possible to configure mailman so that the original sender is also added as 'Cc'? Or is there a way to only set the 'Reply-To' field for list members, but keep the original sender als Reply-To when he is not a member of the list?